# Format data served from MySql via PHP PDO to feed Googe Charts on the Visualization API

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

I need to generate decision trees from a MYSQL v 5.6 table, queried with PHP  PDO.  I have a nice query which gives the data required, however I can't find the correct format to parse data to the Google API.

I searched and found a myriad of articles on how to format data to feed Google Charts.  However the common denominator is the use of the infamous and deprecated mysql_query class to fetch data, and some addrow method which I found quite strange and UnClean.

I'm asking how should I format the json output in order to porperly feed the API.  At the moment I query the data, json encode it using PHP's **json_encode**, and get the data properly via **AJAX**.  Indeed my console shows that the data is properly read by the browser,  however I know there is a format issue.

Unfortuantely tha google visualization API doesn't give me info on where the error could be.  I just received this message:

```
Invalid format in explicit format: column #0 must be of type 'number'
```

Well this is a sample of data that the google javascript receives:

```
[{"id":"1","elemento":"CLIO","parent":"0","size":306},  {"id":"2","elemento":"LOGAN","parent":"0","size":431},  {"id":"3","elemento":"SANDERO","parent":"0","size":335},
```

On the other way,  I'm following strictly the Google visualization guidelines to use data from external data sources:
[Populating Data Using Server-Side Code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example?csw=1)

and specifically the chart that I need to render [Wordtrees](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree#full), which uses and **arrayToDataTable** method to format properly the data.

What should I correct in order to get and/or read the proper formatted json string of data?  Please keep in mind the previous example of actual data which uses:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

to JSON format the query output.  Should I construct a table?  How to do it in a proper, clean and modern way,  not the mysql_query iteration.

Thanks for your time and collaboration.

Comment: can you show us how are you initializing the chart in javascript?

Comment: the data format is flexible but you do need to meet certain criteria, you can find examples in the [DataTable Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#datatable-class) reference